# Display select dropdown and date values from database to edit form

Tags: html, laravel, forms, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to pass the value of my database in `Dropdown` and `Date` Inputs Form.

My `$variable->dataname` is `$employee->gender` and `$employee->birthdate`.

Here is my dropdown:

```
 {{Form::select('gender',['male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female'],
                            ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Gender...'])}}
```

Here is my date input:

```
{{Form::date('birthdate', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

How can I edit those without their values are getting removed?

Comment: ive got an answer sir , but do you want to answer my another question please see here .. [see link here please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647423/laravel-ajax-when-search-it-duplicates-data?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the options array which is last the collective package accepts the 3d parameter as a default/selected value.

So for your select you can use:

```
{{Form::select('gender',['male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female'], old('gender', $employee->gender),
                        ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Gender...'])}}
```

and the date:

```
{{Form::date('birthdate', old('birthdate', $employee->birthdate), ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Comment: I can mark your answer as correct in 4 mins sir, thanks it worked btw, but how about input="file" ? can i also use `old` function on that ?

Comment: No, you can show a link to an uploaded file if there is any. So the user can review if he still wants to use the same one or use the field to upload a new one.

Comment: so how can I display the file when i edit the page? coz everytime im editing it was removed

Comment: That happens because you are updating all the fields, without checking if there is a new value for the file in particular. So for files, in your controller method for updating you can check if new file has been uploaded with `request()->has('file_field_name')` then update that field, otherwise leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**On your Select**

```
{{Form::select('gender',['male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female'],(isset($employee)?$employee->gender:null),
                        ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Gender...'])}}
```

**On your Date**

```
{{Form::date('birthdate',(isset($employee)?$employee->birthdate:null), ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Make sure you are passing your data on `$employee`.

Hope this will help you