# Laravel - Ajax when Search it Duplicates data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Hello when I search in the textbox the data duplicates itself why?

Here is my ajax code. Please check this code as it is the problem why it is duplicating. Also please make sure that the syntax of it is correct.

```
$('#search').on('keyup',function(){
    $value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url  : '{{ URL::to('admin/employeemaintenance/search') }}',
        data : {'search':$value},
        success:function(data){
            $('tbody').html(data);
        }
    });
})
```

My controller

Please check this code it might have some issue, I might have some huge data fields, also the buttons which are the update and remove are still not included here :

```
    public function search(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $output="";
        $employees = DB::table('employeefms')->where('last_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                                             ->orWhere('first_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();


        if($employees)
        {
            foreach($employees as $key => $employee){
                if($employee->gender==0)
                {
                    $gender="Male";
                }
                else
                {
                    $gender="Female";
                }
            $output.='<tr>'.
                     '<td>'.$employee->employee_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->last_name.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->first_name.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->middle_name.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->nick_name.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$gender.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->birthdate.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->age.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->birthplace.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->province.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->doMarriage.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->height.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->weight.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->bloodtype.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->nationality.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->religion.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->civil_stats.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->sss_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->tin_id.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->phil_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->pagibig_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->address_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->street_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->brgy.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->municipality.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->cur_province.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->region.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->zipcode.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->per_address_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->per_street_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->per_brgy.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->per_municipality.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->per_province.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->per_region.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->per_zipcode.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->mobile_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->tel_no.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->email_ad.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->guard_name.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->guard_add.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->guard_relat.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$employee->grd_mobile_no.'</td>'.
                    '<a href="/admin/employeemaintenance/'.$employee->id.'/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'.
                    '</tr>';
            }
            return Response($output);
        }
    }
}
```

My search textbox

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control">
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question but please but the $output inside your views, the controller is not the place to put html.

Comment: What is the response from the backend?

Comment: @CsabaGergely what response do you mean sir?

Comment: @Christophvh if i remove the $output i cannot search no data will be searched

Comment: The ajax's response ( data )

Comment: @Alex Malikov, why did you delete ur answer sir?

Comment: oh it is the $output it is responding back at the inputs in my controller

Comment: @CsabaGergely Help me with the correct code please

Comment: @Christophvh Help me with the correct code please :(

Comment: Put a console.log(data) to your ajax success, and check the response. Your js code looks good, it might be a duplicate in your database, because the html() function overwrites the tbody html. Check the html code you may have two tbody inside your table.

Comment: Just a thought not sure if its right or not, can you try  ```DISTINCT()``` on your query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put html in laravel controller, you can return the $employees as data and then add html in your ajax success action

Answer (score -1):

```
public function search(Request $request){
if($request->ajax())
{

    $employees = DB::table('employeefms')->where('last_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                                         ->orWhere('first_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();


    if(!empty($employees))
    {
        return json_encode(array("msg"=>"success", "data"=>$employees));
    }
     return json_encode(array("msg"=>"error"));
}
```

}

\\\\\\\\\ Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url  : '{{ URL::to('admin/employeemaintenance/search') }}',
        data : {'search':$value},
        success:function(data){
           var data1 = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
           if(data1.msg == "success"){
                $.each(eval(data1.data), function(){
                      //html here
                    })
             },
             //no data found

        }
    });
```

Comment: 1. You don't need to encode return to JSON. Laravel makes it automatically. 2. If your backend returns json, you can just add `dataType: 'json'` param to AJAX code and don't need to reinvent the wheel with parsing JSON.

Comment: Yes, it true, i work allows with pure PHP i forgot that laravel  automatically encode retun to JSON